# DocuSign - Error UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT on Create envelope REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated DocuSign REST in Oracle Fusion Procurement Cloud Application.

We are calling create envelope API using the endpoint:

**https://docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{AccountID}/envelopes**

This api is failing for few customers with error:

> UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT

for docx and xlxs attachments type. If document converted to PDF manually and again used in REST api call then getting error:

> PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED

But same attachment is working fine if customer upload it directly in the envelope from DocuSign UI.

This is impacting our customer business. Every time they have to withdraw purchasing document, remove attachment from purchasing document and explicitly add those attachment in the envelope from DocuSign UI. Any pointers on the error resolution is much appreciated. Please help.

Actual Error Message received:

> UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENTSystem
>   was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert
>   Document(xxxxxxxxxx.docx) to a PDF. Error: UserId:xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx
>   IPAddress:xxx.xx.xx.xx Source:ApiRESTv2:Conversion failed. FileType:
>   docx   Error: ActivePDF completed without success: [-1100]
>   OpenInputFileFailed

Create Envelope REST api should work for those attachment as it is working from DocuSign UI.

Comment: Can you please share the JSON req body, also are you passing file extension property in the JSON Req body?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a support case with DocuSign customer support.

I'm sorry that you're having this problem.

**Update**

I have discussed your question with DocuSign Engineering. The experts believe that there should be no difference between submitting a document to DocuSign via the API vs the DocuSign web tool.

Please provide a (sanitized) version of the document that causes the error to DocuSign customer support. Please ask support to copy me, Larry Kluger, on the support ticket.

Comment: We are working with our customer to open a support case. So, they can share documents through appropriate channel for analysis.

Comment: Hi Larry Kluger, Thank you for your prompt response. We have involved DocuSign Global Partner Solutions team for this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue with my integration. The DocuSign service was failing to convert a docx file to pdf.

```
Response code 400
{
  "errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document([omitted].docx) to a PDF. Error: UserId:[omitted] IPAddress:[omitted] Source:ApiRESTv2:Conversion failed. FileType: docx  Error: ActivePDF completed without success: [-1100] OpenInputFileFailed"
}
```

In my case the operation succeeded after I removed the page # from the footer of the document.

Comment: Thank you for the report. Next time, please open a new StackOverflow question and then answer it yourself since you found an answer to your problem. Meanwhile, if issues of your organization's information security allow you to send the document to us, please do so via DocuSign customer support. We want the document that didn't work. Thanks.